# Calculating sum and average of an array with user input and functions in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, input

beginner C coder here and I'm trying to figure out what exactly is going wrong with my code. I'm using two functions to calculate the sum and average of an array that a user inputted. The size of the array is determined by the user. I've tried looking up examples but am not finding many helpful tips. It's more likely that I'm just not understanding what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please grant me some constructive criticism and guidance. Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*function declarations*/
int addNumbers(int number[]); 
float avgNumbers(int sum, int n);

int main(){
    int i, n, number[100], sum, result;
    float average;

    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)  
   {
       printf("Enter the numbers %d:\n", i+1);
       scanf("%d",&number[i]);
   }
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)  
    {
       sum = 0;
       sum = addNumbers(&number);
       average = avgNumbers(sum,n);
    }

    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    printf("Average: %f\n",average);

    return 0;
}

/*function returning the sum of the numbers*/
int addNumbers(int number[])
{
    int i, n, sum;
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    sum += number[i]; 
    return sum;
    }

/*function returning the average of the numbers*/
float avgNumbers(int sum, int n)
{
    average = sum/n
    return average;
    }
```

Comment: The problem very likely is that when both of arguments `sum` and `n` are `int`s, avgNumbers does integer division, rounding down. You must cast either of the arguments to `float`, i.e. `(float)sum/n` Rather than use `double` for the average as not all of `int`s range is covered by float.

Comment: And also, you're not passing the `n` to `addNumbers` as an argument. You got some compilation errors - the errors need to be added into the question

Comment: Please read the [mcve] page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of for loop while calling addNumbers() and avgNumbers(). Also you are sending the address in place of value in method. Replace your code with this code.

```
sum = 0;
sum = addNumbers(number);
average = avgNumbers(sum,n);
```

Comment: If you think it is solution for your problem. Please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You no need loop in the main function because of you already a loop in your `addNumber(int number[])` but you need to pass the number of elements in the array as an argument to `addNumbers(int number[], int n)` like this. And you are assigning `sum = 0` in the `for` loop every time. In `avgNumbers(int sum, int n )` you need to declare `average` and assign 0 to it.

Your code should be like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*function declarations*/
int addNumbers (int number[], int n);
float avgNumbers (int sum, int n);

int main (){
    int i, n, number[100], sum, result;
    float average;

    printf ("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf ("Enter the numbers %d:\n", i + 1);
        scanf ("%d", &number[i]);
    }
    sum = 0;
    sum = addNumbers(number, n);
    average = avgNumbers(sum, n);


    printf ("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf ("Average: %f\n", average);
    return 0;
}

/*function returning the sum of the numbers*/
int addNumbers (int number[], int n){
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += number[i];
    return sum;
}

/*function returning the average of the numbers*/
float avgNumbers (int sum, int n){
    float average = 0;
    average = sum / n;
    return average;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using return type float while calculating average but the parameters are int . In this case when you divide sum by n only the integer part is stored and hence the average value you will obtain be incorrect. You must typecast your value before actually performing division. Typecasting is very necessary else incorrect results may be produced.

The next thing is you donot need for loop in the main function

```
#include<stdio.h>
/*function declarations*/
int addNumbers (int number[], int n);
float avgNumbers (int sum, int n);

int main (){
    int i, n, number[100], sum, result;
    float average;

    printf ("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf ("Enter the numbers %d:\n", i + 1);
        scanf ("%d", &number[i]);
    }
    sum = 0;
    sum = addNumbers(number, n);
    average = avgNumbers(sum, n);


    printf ("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf ("Average: %f\n", average);
    return 0;
}

/*function returning the sum of the numbers*/
int addNumbers (int number[], int n){
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += number[i];
    return sum;
}

/*function returning the average of the numbers*/
float avgNumbers (int sum, int n){
    float average = 0;
    average = (float)sum / n;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everyone here has made it a lot easier to understand for me. Now I can see what I did wrong.